# What is wrong with my image slide show code?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, slideshow

I'm trying to make an image cycle through a set of images, when you click a button. Why won't it work? I want to make sure the images are preloaded, so that it will not make the website slower.

```js
var ImageSet = new Array();
ImageSet[0] = ImageOne;
ImageOne = newImage();
ImageSet[0].src = 'Website/Images/CoverPhotos/LogoCover.jpg';
ImageSet[1] = ImageTwo;
ImageTwo = newImage();
ImageSet[1].src = 'http://p1.pichost.me/i/64/1886374.jpg';
ImageSet[2] = ImageThree;
ImageThree = newImage();
ImageSet[2].src = 'http://abduzeedo.com/files/originals/5/50cuteanimpic6.jpg';
ImageSet[3] = ImageFour;
ImageFour = newImage();
ImageSet[3].src = 'http://www.onsecrethunt.com/wallpaper/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Cool-Wallpapers-Card-Pictures-1200x675.jpg';

var ImageSwitchNo = 0;

function Change() {

if (ImageSwitchNo < 3) {
ImageSwitchNo++;
}else {
ImageSwitchNo = 0;
}
var ImageSrc = document.getElementById('HeaderPhotoImage').innerHTML;
ImageSrc.src = ImageSet[3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving ImageOne a value on line three after trying to store it in the array on the line before it.

Instead of this:

```
var ImageSet = new Array();
ImageSet[0] = ImageOne;
ImageOne = newImage();
ImageSet[0].src = 'Website/Images/CoverPhotos/LogoCover.jpg';
```

try doing it like this for all of them:

```
var ImageSet = [];
ImageOne = newImage(); //gives ImageOne a value.
ImageSet[0] = ImageOne;  //THEN sets the index of ImageSet to that value.
ImageSet[0].src = 'Website/Images/CoverPhotos/LogoCover.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code may work if you change the second line from bottom,

```
ImageSrc.src = ImageSet[3];
```

to

```
ImageSrc.src = ImageSet[ImageSwitchNo];
```